# cannot find module RecipeStyle.css

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created a css file and want it to include it on a jsx file. I installed css loader and style-loader and babel. I imported the css file in my script but it shows me the error message: can not find moudle ./...

but why?

i watched tutorials and followed everything i even deleted the node modules folder and reloaded it with npm install

Recipe.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { IngredientFormPart } from './IngredientFormPart';

import './RecipeStyle.css';

export class RecipeForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <label>
                    Name des Rezepts
                    <input
                        id="recipeID"
                        type="text"
                        />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <IngredientFormPart />
                </label>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path    = require('path');
var hwp     = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader'
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', 'css' ]
      },
    plugins:[
        new hwp({template:path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html')})
    ]
}
```

.babel config

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-state",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ddd ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"css"` in `resolve.extensions` to `".css"`.